# Using a modal to display a dynamic form?

Tags: data-tables, modal-windows, lean-ux

So currently I am building an interface that consists of user created "Documents" which can have a variable number of "items" associated with it. The problem is that I am not sure what is the most ideal method to represent the aforementioned user workflows. Below is an early stage prototype which illustrates the issues.Would really appreciate any feedback on how I can improve the solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't recommend Modals for a Form. Ideal usage of modal should be to show information or present choice for the user eg - left or right. Forms shouldn't be presented in modals as they limit the experience as well as has high changes of User errors of dismissing the modal before complete etc...